# Embed Power BI on an on-premises ASP.NET web app with windows authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, powerbi, powerbi-embedded, asp.net-authentication

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 web application hosted on an on premises server IIS. The web app uses windows authentication which is further verified against user entries in an SQL server table, so there's no AD authentication.

We have some Power BI reports hosted online on cloud and want to embed them in our app. Online resources say to register the application on Azure AD. Does this involve moving the application to azure or using some sort of Azure AD authentication api in the application.

We are novice in both in Power BI and Azure AD. How do we provide a sort of like SSO authentication across our application and the embedded report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the app registrations is for managing your app rights when using the Power BI API. This is a simple registration, which will give you an unique App ID to be used later. Your actual application can stay on-premise. So you simply need to follow the [Embed Power BI content into an application for your customers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-sample-for-customers) tutorial. Please note, the way its made it requires to buy a Power BI Embedded (at least A1) or Power BI Premium capacity.